# flutter web dialog and keyboard overflow error on mobile

Tags: flutter

**Current**

I'm building a flutter web page to gain location information from user.
Code below first check if width is less than 840, if it is run locationAsk function which is future of futureBuilder inside screenSwitch. If location package weren't able to gain location, it make popup to ask user to input location.

```
  return Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
    body: Builder(builder: (context) {
      return screenSwitch(width, height, mediaQuery);
    }));

  screenSwitch(width, height, mediaQuery) {
    double normalFont = 0;
    double titleFont = 0;
    if (width < 840) {
      normalFont = width * 0.02;
      titleFont = width * 0.035;
      return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: height,
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
  　
  　　　　　　　　##省略
  　
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: FutureBuilder(
                    future: locationAsk(mediaQuery),
                    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<void> snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {

                        ##省略

                      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
                          final Uri _url = Uri.parse("url");
                          _launchUrl(_url);
                        });
                        return SizedBox(
                            width: width * 0.7,
                            child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                              "リダイレクトします",
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: normalFont, decoration: TextDecoration.none, color: Colors.black),
                            )));
                      } else {
                        Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
                          final Uri _url = Uri.parse("url");
                          _launchUrl(_url);
                        });
                        return SizedBox(
                            width: width * 0.7,
                            child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                              "リダイレクトします",
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: normalFont, decoration: TextDecoration.none, color: Colors.black),
                            )));
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),

  Future<void> locationAsk(mediaQuery) async {
    Location location = Location();
    bool serviceEnabled;
    PermissionStatus permissionGranted;
    LocationData locationData;
    serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
    permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
    }
    if (serviceEnabled && permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
      permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
    }
    if (serviceEnabled && permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      locationData = await location.getLocation();
    } else {
      // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
      await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: AlertDialog(
              backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
              content: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  const Text("現在地を共有いただけますか？"),
                  SizedBox(
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: _location,
                    ),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                      child: const Text("送信 / submit"))
                ],
              ),
              actions: [
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    child: const Text("閉じる/close"))
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
      return;
    }
  }
```

**Problem**

On mobile, when user click on textField inside locationAsk function keyboard popup which cause overflow (i assume). When keyboard popup, it automatically go back down, background of popup become dark and any action is refused.

**Tried solution**

to fix the issue i tried

- add resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false to Scaffold
- add Builder
- add singlechildscrollview to every possible place
- make popup smaller
- push every element in screenSwitch into sizedbox

which non worked

**information**

I'm using locationAsk function as future to send gained information to firebase before redirecting to next page.
I'm developing it on vscode on Windows therefore I have not been able to confirm the cause of error.
I've also tried to use android device to test it out but cause Invalid depfile: C:\Users...\flutter_prac error which I also could not find a way to fix it and give it up.
please help me with your knowledge.

Comment: Can you post a MRE?